# Facebook notification pop ups

Tags: notifications, facebook

I tried to turn off Facebook notifications in my System Preferences on my OSX 10.9.1 but they still won't go away. What am I doing wrong? I unchecked all the boxes but it insists on showing me pop up balloons in the top right corner of my screen every time I get a notification. How can I make it go away??? Do I need to re-boot my computer in order for it to work?

Comment: What program generates those notifications?

Comment: I tried the methods suggested in that link, but it did not work. The notifications still pop up. I am not sure what program generates the pop ups. I assumed it was part of the OSX.

Comment: I figured it out. In System Preferences, I forgot to change the Facebook alert style to "none" instead of balloons. I think this solved the matter. Thanks!

Comment: Lyra, if you posted this as your answer it would be helpful to future users.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, or at least it may have a different answer. The question that "already has an answer" has an answer specific to Mountain Lion. The Notifications system pref pane looks different for other versions of Mac OS X. I have the same question as both of these users but for El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Mine did not turn off even when I logged out of FaceBook, BUT they did turn off when I went into my settings on Facebook, clicked on notifications, and turned them off :3